# Generate array of random unique numbers in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate an array of random numbers from 0-n then shuffle (but ensure that the keys and values DO NOT match).

For example:

```
0 => 3
1 => 2
2 => 4
3 => 0
4 => 1
```

Note that both keys and values are from 0-4 but none of the keys and values are the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try something ? It seems very basic...

Comment: Just curious, what you need this for?

Comment: Must there be absolutely no key=>value matches? Does the range of keys have to match the range of values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$max = 5;
$done = false;
while(!$done){
    $numbers = range(0, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $done = true;
    foreach($numbers as $key => $val){
        if($key == $val){
            $done = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant, but prone to lock up when scaled.

Comment: True. It's a really simple script just for myself though. No need to worry about scaling.

Comment: you could add a safety to make sure that the code doesnt exceed a certain number of loops outside loops: `$rounds = 1;` inside foreach loop `if($rounds++ >= 10000){ break 2; }`

Answer (score 31):

A even shorter solution:

```
$random_number_array = range(0, 100);
shuffle($random_number_array );
$random_number_array = array_slice($random_number_array ,0,10);

print_r($random_number_array);
```

Result will be:

```
[0] => 53
[1] => 6
[2] => 16
[3] => 59
[4] => 8
[5] => 18
[6] => 62
[7] => 39
[8] => 22
[9] => 26
```

Comment: Here it's not ensured, that the result array doesn't contain matching key-value pairs: `shuffle([1,2,3])` might return an array like `[0=>2,1=>1,2=>0]`, meaning some keys might be equal to their values. A further point: As I understand the question correctly, the set of the numbers for the keys and the values of the result array should be the same, meaning like `[0=>2,1=>0,2=>1]` and not like `[0=>58,1=>74,2=>49]`. Seems, that we have to make multiple attempts and use a loop like `do-while`.

Answer (score 6):

This will generate an array with 10 random numbers from 0 to 100:

```php
array_map(function () {
       return rand(0, 100);
   }, array_fill(0, 10, null));
```

Result:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  int(15)
  [1]=>
  int(97)
  [2]=>
  int(20)
  [3]=>
  int(64)
  [4]=>
  int(57)
  [5]=>
  int(38)
  [6]=>
  int(16)
  [7]=>
  int(53)
  [8]=>
  int(56)
  [9]=>
  int(22)
}
```

Explanation:

- `array_fill(0, 10, null)` will generate an array with 10 empty items
- `array_map` Applies the callback (first argument) to each item of the array it receives (second argument). In this example, we just return a random number for each array item.

Playground: https://3v4l.org/FffN6

If you need to make sure each generated number is unique:

```php
$uniqueNumbers = 100;
$picked = [];
$uniqueRandomNumbers = array_map(function () use(&$picked, $uniqueNumbers) {
    do {
      $rand = rand(0, $uniqueNumbers);
    } while(in_array($rand, $picked));

    $picked[] = $rand;

    return $rand;
}, array_fill(0, $uniqueNumbers, null));
```

https://3v4l.org/mSWBo#v8.0.9

Answer (score 3):

Naive solution:

```
$n = 10;
$rands = array();
for($i=0; $i<$n;$i++) {
  $ok = false;
  while(!$ok) {
    $x=mt_rand(0,$n-1);
    $ok = !in_array($x, $rands) && $x != $i;
  }
  $rands[$i]=$x;
}

var_dump($rands);
```

Efficient solution:

```
$n = 100;  
$numbers = range(0, $n-1);
$rands = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  $ok = false;
  while (!$ok) {
    $x = array_rand($numbers);
    $ok = !in_array($numbers[$x], $rands) && $numbers[$x] != $i;
  }
  $rands[$i] = $numbers[$x];
  unset($numbers[$x]);
}

var_dump($rands);
```

**edit:** s/rand/mt_rand/

**edit #2:** both solutions can end up in a deadlock, as mentioned by @AMayer. I stand corrected.

Comment: mt_rand() gives a much more random result.

Comment: @zi42 if you array looks like `array(1=>3, 2=>1, 3=>2)` and `$n=5` then your array will loop forever. the only option left is 4 and 4!=4 so your while loop will keep going. You would need to redo the whole array.

Comment: You're right. I stand corrected. I will keep my bad solution up for educational purposes :)

Comment: @zi42 Ive done things like that before too. Thats the only reason I caught it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rather long, but also pretty efficient solution, I believe. Contrary to other solutions posted here, this cannot deadlock (unless `$size<2`), and this will not do a full shuffle every time one value doesn't fit. Instead, it will only replace that value with another, random value.

```
function unique_list($size=5) {

    function all_unique($numbers) {
        foreach ($numbers as $key=>$value)
            if ($key==$value) return false;
        return true;
    }
    function flip($a, $b, &$numbers) {
        $numbers[$a] = $numbers[$a] + $numbers[$b];
        $numbers[$b] = $numbers[$a] - $numbers[$b];
        $numbers[$a] = $numbers[$a] - $numbers[$b];
    }

    $flip_count = 0;
    $numbers = range(0,$size-1);
    shuffle($numbers);

    while (!all_unique($numbers)) {
        foreach ($numbers as $key=>$value) {
            if ($key==$value) {
                flip($key, rand(0,$size-1), $numbers);
                $flip_count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Flipped %d values\n", $flip_count);
    return $numbers;

}

$list = unique_list(10);
print_r($list);
```

The above will print something similar to

```
Flipped 1 value(s)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** generate an array of unique random
 *  numbers within a given range
**/

function generateRandomNumbers($end, $total, $start = 0, $numbers = [])
{
    if(count($numbers) == $total) {
        return $numbers;
    }
    $number = rand($start, $end);

    if(!in_array($number, $numbers)) {
        $numbers[] = $number;

    }
    return generateRandomNumbers($end, $total, $start, $numbers);
}
```

Here is an example to generate **30** numbers within range **9 - 100**:

```
$end = 100; 
$total = 30;
$start = 9;
generateRandomNumbers($end, $total, $start);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's about combining `range(...)` (for generating the original array first), `shuffle(...)` (to randomize the array), and `array_intersect_assoc(...)` (for checking the result array)?

```
$numbers = range(0, 4);
do {
    shuffle($numbers); // print_r($numbers);
    $matchingKeyValuePairs = array_intersect_assoc(array_keys($numbers), array_values($numbers)); // print_r($matchingKeyValuePairs);
} while (! empty($matchingKeyValuePairs));
```

This solution might bring some performance issues for big numbers of elements. But it can be extended by a logic for dealing with the `$matchingKeyValuePairs`. So while now the logic is like "IF there are `matchingKeyValuePairs` THEN try it again", a much more efficient logic migth be "IF there are `matchingKeyValuePairs` THEN cut the `matchingKeyValuePairs` from the array,  randomize this sub-array (multiple times, if needed), and merge it back".

Answer (score 0):

The approach here is to create a range of numbers from 0 to n, and then shuffle.
We then look for key value matches, and swap pairs of them.  If we don't have a pair to swap, we swap with the last item, unless the item is the last item, then we swap with the first.

```
<?php
$n = 5;
$values = range(0, $n);
shuffle($values);
$matched = array_filter($values, function($v, $k) {return $k === $v;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
foreach(array_chunk($matched, 2) as list($a, $b)) {
    if($b === null) {
        $swap_key = array_key_last($values);
        if($swap_key == $a) {
            $swap_key = array_key_first($values);
        }
        list($values[$a], $values[$swap_key]) = [$values[$swap_key], $a];
    } else {
        list($values[$a], $values[$b]) = [$b, $a];
    }
}
```

Example shuffle when n is 5:

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 5,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 3,
  4 => 4,
  5 => 2,
)
```

Here we have matches for keys:

```
0, 3 and 4.
```

So we swap the values for keys 0 and 3, and 4 with the last.

```
array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 5,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 2,
  5 => 4,
)
```

(`array_key_first` could be swapped for 0 given the range here.  I've left it as it is more explicit.)

Comment: Not sure if there is an issue with the proximity swaps on the matched item pairs.  May be an idea to further shuffle the matched array.  Would be interested on other's takes here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getUniqueArray($value, $total)
{
    $array = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $value; $i++) {
        $rand = rand(0, $total);
        if (in_array($rand, $array))
            $i--;
        else
            array_push($array, rand(0, $total));
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).