# avoid duplicates amongst creating random numbers

Tags: php, random, numbers, generator

if I want to create some variables that contain random numbers that differ from each other, right now this is the method i'm using(in this case i'm using PHP to set example):

```
while($rand1==$rand2 or $rand2==$rand3 or $rand3==$rand4 or $rand4==$rand5 or
rand1==$rand3 or $rand2==$rand4 or $rand3==$rand5 or $rand5==$rand4 or  
$rand1==$rand4 or $rand2==$rand5 or $rand4==$rand3 or $rand5==$rand3 or 
$rand1==$rand5 or $rand3==$rand2 or $rand4==$rand1 or $rand5==$rand2 or 
$rand2==$rand1 or $rand3==$rand1 or $rand4==$rand2 or $rand5==$rand1):

$rand1=rand(1,1000); 
$rand2=rand(1,1000); 
$rand3=rand(1,1000); 
$rand4=rand(1,1000); 
$rand5=rand(1,1000); 
endwhile;
```

so, if I want to create 100 variables all with differing numbers,I wouldn't want to use this method for obvious reason. Any better alternatives?

Comment: do you know anything about Arrays?

Comment: well, maybe that's why I asked

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824770/generate-array-of-random-unique-numbers-in-php

Answer (score 0):

put them in an array and search the array.
`$arr = array();
$arr[] = rand(1,1000);`

You can just loop through as many as you like

Comment: I'm stuck on the "searching" part.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume you need numbers from 1 to 1000 and you don't want duplicates. Here's a way not to loop through your random numbers every time since it's time consuming if you need 100 random numbers:

```
$pool = range(1, 1000);
$numbers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0, count($pool) - 1);
    $numbers[$i] = $pool[$random];
    $pool[$random] = array_pop($pool);
}
```

Just change `5` to whatever you need or use a variable.

This works if you have a pool of numbers to extract from, that's why we pop the last element and we replace the number we extracted already to avoid duplicates. We have to count the elements in the pool each time because it shrinks by one element on each iteration. You could probably save the initial value and decrement it based on `$i` if your pool is not a native array so you don't waste time counting and you just do basich math.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you 5 unique randoms in the given range:

```
$a = range(1, 1000);
shuffle($a);
$randoms = array_slice($a, 0, 5);
```

(I assume performance is not critical).

In a more efficient way,

```
$randoms = array();
while(count($randoms) < 5)
    $randoms[rand(1, 1000)] = 1;
$randoms = array_keys($randoms);
```